# JqPlot: Set min/max on date axis

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Need some advice around setting the maximum value on a DateAxisRenderer axis - I've tried pad, no luck. Assuming I want the xaxis maximum to be one day greater than my last date, how would I set this?

```
       xaxis:{ max:'??', tickInterval: '86400000', renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, tickOptions:{ formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d' }}
```

Comment: Check pad property http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.pad

Comment: pad property doesn't work with the DateAxisRenderer - therein lies the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the biggest x-value of your serie using :

> `var biggest_day = plot2.axes.xaxis._dataBounds.max`.

Adding 1 day to this value is done by

> `biggest_day += 86400000` (time in millisecond).

You can then apply this new bound to your plot doing

> `plot1.axes.xaxis.max = biggest_day`

Finally, don't forget to replot : `plot1.replot()`

Comment: Thanks Anthony - that works. I had a change of heart since posting my question and approached the problem differently anyway. Thanks just the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to define min and max from yaxis, you can do this: [enter link description here][1]

HTML

```
<div id="chart" style="height:500px"></div>
```

Scripts

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var line1=[['1', 0.0],['2', 8.3],['3', 10.1],['4', 10.0],['5', 8.3],['6', 8.3],['7', 20.8],['8', 23.8],['9', 27.1],['10', 23.8],['11', 22.3],['12', 24.4]];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart', [line1], {
title:'Default Date Axis',
axes:{
    xaxis:{
        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{formatString:'%b'},
    },
    yaxis:{
        //renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{formatString: '%.1f %'},
        min:0,
        max:100,
        tickInterval:'10'
    }
}, 
 series:[{color:'#5FAB78'}], 
 highlighter: { 
     show: false, 
     sizeAdjust: 1 
 }, 
 cursor: { 
     show: false 
 },
 seriesDefaults: {  
      showMarker:true, 
      pointLabels: { show:true }  
 } 
 });
});
```